# Sony SmartEyeglass: How can I mirror Sony SmartEyeglass screen to Andorid handset or PC?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I want to show others what I can see on on Sony SmartEyeglass which I have worn. Is there any way to mirror it on paired Android handset screen or PC?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a screen capture of the SmartEyeglass or mirror it.  If you are asking about capturing the output from the Camera to display on the Android device, then it is possible using the Camera API.  See the Camera guide for more details:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/camera/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emulator provided to run your app on an Android device and then something like Droid@Screen on PC to show the display of Android device.
The only problem in this case is you would expect seeing the real world behind on the emulator instead of a black background.